# Enabling ActiveSyncDebugLogging doesn't work

Tags: powershell, exchange-2010

We have an Exchange 2010 server that's using ActiveSync to sync with iPhone devices. For some reason, random emails are not being synced to the device.

I am trying to review debug logging for the activesync but failing to enable this attribute. Has anyone experience this weird issue, and know the resolution to it?

Set-Casmailbox user1 -ActiveSyncDebugLogging:$true

Doesn't matter how many times or where I run this command, or when I run it for multiple users. I don't seem to be able to modify this attribute. Am I missing something?

[image: Fail to enable ActiveSyncDebugLogging]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bit confusing since the attribute doesn't seem to show modified when running the normal `get-casmailbox` command, but adding the `-ActiveSyncDebugLogging` parameter to that command should confirm it for you.

Try this on the user you have enabled logging on:

```
Get-CASMailbox user1 -ActiveSyncDebugLogging | fl name,*logg*
```

You *should* see that is actually enabled.  After which, you can try and reproduce the issue and issue this command to look at the log:

```
Get-MobileDeviceStatistics -Mailbox user1 -GetMailboxLog:$true | clip
```